# how to have holidays of different countries shown on OS X default app?

Tags: macos, calendar

I have US holidays and in the settings there is Chinese calendar too. But I want to have holidays of a few different countries included in the calendar simultaneously. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 3):

Apple has a [website with all supported calendars](https://www.apple.com/downloads/macosx/calendars/).  You can download and install dozens of different types of calendars on your Mac.

Simply find the calendar you want to use, download it, and then install it into your calendar. If you sync your calendar with iCloud, these dates will also be added there.  If you don't know how to do that, see [this Apple Support site](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202835) for directions on how to add calendars.

If you have any iOS calendars that sync to this calendar, they will also be updated with the new dates.

Comment: are these uptodate? and I just had a look the calendar of the country that I want is not listed there. are there other options?

Comment: These are just the Apple-authorized calendars.  You didn't mention the country you were looking for.  You can search Google for other sites that host calendars but I'm surprised that Apple doesn't have the country you're looking for.